# Multiple layouts with SwiftKey and physical keyboard?

Tags: external-keyboard, swiftkey

I use SwiftKey with external Bluetooth and OTG keyboards. SwiftKey is designed for this.

However, SwiftKey only gives me the English keyboard layout. When using the soft keyboard, my layout is Norwegian, and I alternate between typing in Norwegian and English. Norwegian layout is important to me as it contains special characters.

How can I get Norwegian (or any other latin-based) layout when using the hard keyboard with SwiftKey?

What is the easiest way to switch between different layouts quickly while using a physical keyboard with SwiftKey? (Something akin to the Samsung stock keyboard's <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> Shortcut)

My details: Samsung I9305 running rooted stock 4.4.4 with Xposed Framework and SwitKey 6.1.0.71.

Answer (score 0):

With swiftkey you can configure the hardware keyboard input in the "voice and other inputs" option under the "typing" section. The configuration is rather limited though, and for example doesn't allow for (let alone let you choose) a shortcut to open the virtual keyboard (the google keyboard does this on the pixel c).

[image: Screenshot of the menu]

In the 3rd option from the left on the top row.

Comment: Where in the interface can I find the "other inputs" option?

Comment: May I know if the screenshot is from Pixel C? It looks different from the most of Android Settings screen.